# Not able to retrieve XML tag nested within content of another tag 

Tags: android, xml, parsing, sax

Thanks for reading!

Using XML parsing tutorial from [here](http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html) as a reference, I am trying to parse a simple XML RSS feed with the following structure.

Everything works fine and all values are parsed except for the following case: I am not able to get the content of the `<img>` tag.

```
<feed>
    <title>This is Title</title>
    <count>10</count>
    <desc>
        This is a description for a sample feed <img src="http://someimagelink.com/img.jpg" />
    </desc>
    <link>This is link</link>
</feed>
```

This is what the `endElement()` method looks like:

```
        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equals("feed")) {
            //Add Records object to ArrayList
            //Feed is a POJO class to store all the feed content. 
            //FeedList is an ArrayList to store multiple Feed objects.
            mFeedList.add(mFeed); 
        }
        else if(localName.equals("title")) {
            mFeed.setTitle(currentValue.toString());
        }
        else if(localName.equals("count")) {
            mFeed.setCount(currentValue.toString());
        }
        else if(localName.equals("desc")) {
            mFeed.setDesc(currentValue.toString());
        }
        else if(localName.equals("img")) {
             //NEVER hits here :(
            mFeed.setImageUrl(currentValue.toString());
        }
        else if(localName.equals("link")) {
            //BUT, hits here
            mFeed.setLink(currentValue.toString());
        }
```

Since `<img>` tag is part of `<desc>` tag, the code in last `else if` condition never gets executed.

**Note:** When I read the the `<desc>` tag, I could do a manual `String` search to retrieve the `<img>` tag content. But, I am sure there has to be a more efficient way.

Can someone guide me on to get content of the `<img>` tag?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Updated the `<img>` tag. It is now closed correctly.

**EDIT2:** Updating with `startElement()` code here. Also updated Feed XML and `startElement()` code.

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    if(localName.equals("feed")) {
        //Instantiate Feed object
        mFeed = new Feed();
    }
    else if(localName.equals("title")) {
            currentValue = new StringBuffer("");
            isBuffering = true;
    }
    else if(localName.equals("count")) {
            currentValue = new StringBuffer("");
            isBuffering = true;     
    }
    else if(localName.equals("desc")) {
        currentValue = new StringBuffer("");
        isBuffering = true;
    }
    else if(localName.equals("img")) {
            currentValue = new StringBuffer("");
            isBuffering = true;
        }
    }
    else if(localName.equals("link")) {
        currentValue = new StringBuffer("");
        isBuffering = true;
    }       
}
```

Comment: The XML is not well-formed... "img" tag is never closed...

Comment: OOps sorry I missed closing it while typing the question. The <img> tag is now closed correctly. This is how the feed appears to me now  - how do I extract the contents of the <img> tag? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<img>` tag actually has no character content, and the value you're after has to be pulled out of the attributes.

To do this, you need to override `startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts)`, recognize the `<img>` tag more or less as you're doing, and get the value you need out of the `atts` parameter.

**Debugging help:**

Using this (simple/stupid) handler:

```
package com.donroby.so;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class DebugHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)  throws SAXException {
        printParseInfo("startElement:", uri, localName, qName);
        int attributesLength = attributes.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < attributesLength; i++) {
            printAttributeInfo(attributes, i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)  throws SAXException {
        printParseInfo("endElement:  ", uri, localName, qName);
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] chars, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        String str = "";
        for (int i = start; i < start + length; i++)
          str += chars[i];

        System.out.println("Characters: '" + str + "'");
    }

    private void printAttributeInfo(Attributes attributes, int i) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s URI: '%s', localName: '%s', qName: '%s', Value: '%s'", "Attribute ",
                attributes.getURI(i), attributes.getLocalName(i), attributes.getQName(i), attributes.getValue(i)));
    }

    private void printParseInfo(String type, String uri, String localName, String qName) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s URI: '%s', localName: '%s', qName: '%s'", type, uri, localName, qName));
    }

}
```

```
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'feed'
Characters: '
    '
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'title'
Characters: 'This is Title'
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'title'
Characters: '
    '
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'count'
Characters: '10'
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'count'
Characters: '
    '
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'desc'
Characters: '
        This is a description for a sample feed '
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'img'
Attribute  URI: '', localName: 'src', qName: 'src', Value: 'http://someimagelink.com/img.jpg'
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'img'
Characters: '
    '
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'desc'
Characters: '
    '
startElement: URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'link'
Characters: 'This is link'
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'link'
Characters: '
'
endElement:   URI: '', localName: '', qName: 'feed'
```

This indicates that the`<img>` tag does indeed generate start and end events.

Comment: Actually, I had overriden startElement(), endElement(),  and characters() methods. Now, when I put a breakpoint on the startElement() method and saw that "localName" has values of "desc" followed by "link". It totally skips "img" :( 

I am fairly new to this kind of XML/HTML parsing so don't know the terminologies for this kind of problem. So, even internet searches are futile :( Please help!

Comment: I can't work on it right now, as I have my real job to do, but I'll try to play with your xml this evening and update with some sample parsing code.  It seems to me there *should* be a startElement event generated for the img.

Comment: Sure, I appreciate you taking time on this. Meanwhile, I am actually investigating extracting the <img> tag using Regex but that's the last option on my mind. Looking forward to your insight on a better solution. Thanks!