# Parse the thumbnail url though Defaulthandler in android

Tags: android, xml, sax

```
 Below is the single item from XML :
<item>
<guid>http://www.businessinsider.com/european-markets-open-dec-24-2014-2014-12</guid>
                    <title>10 Things You Need Before European Markets Open</title>
                    <link>http://www.businessinsider.com/european-markets-open-dec-24-2014-2014-12</link>
                    <pubDate>Wed, 24 Dec 2014 02:52:00 -0500</pubDate>
<media:thumbnail url="http://static6.businessinsider.com/image/549a70f0dd0895a63a8b4567/10-things-you-need-before-european-markets-open.jpg" />
                                                                <media:credit>REUTERS/Dylan Martinez</media:credit>
                                    </item>
```

As you have noticed all the tags have end tags accept media:thumnnail and i have to parse the attribute url value from it.

Comment: notice "/>" in the end of "<media:thumbnail"

Comment: yeah but I am using DefaultHandler overrided methods startElement and endElement and charactersSet and its not worknig like other tags.

Comment: so whats your problem anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of having other content, if you need to get attributes from a tag, you do it in your override of the `DefaultHandler` [`startElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes)) method, which will be called with a value in the `Attributes` parameter.

To get the value of a specific attribute name from this parameter, use the `Attributes` [`getValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/Attributes.html#getValue-java.lang.String-) method.

For an example of parsing attributes(though not actually using the `getValue` method), see [my answer to this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709389/not-able-to-retrieve-xml-tag-nested-within-content-of-another-tag/5715935#5715935).